# Linux shell assignment. Execvp failing to execute commands

Tags: c, linux, execvp

I am trying to create a simple shell using C for linux.  I cannot figure out why execvp() keeps failing. I know execvp doesn't require a path to be passed with the arguments.  I tried following someone's recommendation by running the char array of my commands through strtok.

I keep getting execvp has failed: no such file or directory.  I am just passing a simple "ls" as my command to test.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXARGS         20
#define CMDPROMPT       "theshell>"
#define ARGPROMPT       "Next argument: "
#define prompt(n)       printf("%s", (n) == 0 ? CMDPROMPT : ARGPROMPT);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        char arg[MAXARGS] = {0};
        int i = 0,
            should_run = 1, pid, exitstatus;

        while (should_run)
        {
                prompt(*arg);

                fgets(arg, MAXARGS, stdin);                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                            
                char *arg = strtok(arg, " ");                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                            
                char *arg_tok[MAXARGS];                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                            
                while(arg)                                                                                                                                  
                {                                                                                                                                           
                        arg_tok[i++] = arg;                                                                                                                 
                        arg = strtok(NULL, " ");                                                                                                            
                }                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                            
                pid = fork();                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                            
                switch(pid)
                {
                        case -1:
                                perror("Fork Failed\n");
                                exit(1);
                        case 0:
                                execvp(arg_tok[0], arg_tok);
                                perror("execvp has failed");
                                exit(1);
                        default:
                                while( wait(&exitstatus) != pid );
                                printf("Child process exited with status %d, %d\n", exitstatus>>8, exitstatus&0377);
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: When you exit your `while()` loop, you need `arg_tok[i] = NULL; ` or initialize `char *arg_tok[MAXARGS] = {NULL};` -- the next pointer after your last argument must be `NULL`. From `man 3 execvp` you see `"The array of pointers must be terminated by a null pointer."`

Comment: Tried both options, still getting same error message.  If I pass the arg array instead of arg_tok, execvp seems to accept the command, but it doesn't execute and exits from the child process.  I appreciate the response.

Comment: And `char *arg = strtok(arg, " ");` SHADOWS `char arg[MAXARGS] = {0};`. Always compile with **warnings enabled** and for gcc/cland add `-Wshadow` to catch shadowed variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of problems primarily detailed in the comments above. You don't terminate the `execvp()` list of pointers with a `NULL` and you shadow `arg` with `arg` declared as:

```
    char *arg = strtok(arg, " ");
```

and then redeclared as:

```
        char *arg = strtok(arg, " ");
```

And then lastly, you fail to remove the `'\n'` from the string pointed to by the last pointer. Recall, `fgets()` reads and *includes* the `'\n'` in the buffer filled. So simply change your delimiter list for `strtok()` to include `'\n'`, e.g. `" \n"`.

Putting it altogether, you can do:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>                           /* include sys/wait.h for wait() */

#define MAXARGS         20
#define CMDPROMPT       "theshell> "            /* add space after > */
#define ARGPROMPT       "Next argument: "
#define prompt(n)       printf("%s", (n) == 0 ? CMDPROMPT : ARGPROMPT);

int main (void)
{
    char arg[MAXARGS] = "";
    int i = 0,
        should_run = 1, pid, exitstatus;

    while (should_run)
    {
        prompt (0);

        fgets (arg, MAXARGS, stdin);

        char *p = strtok (arg, " \n");           /* fix shadow of arg, included \n as delim */

        char *arg_tok[MAXARGS] = {NULL};

        while (p) {
            arg_tok[i++] = p;
            p = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        }

        pid = fork();

        switch(pid)
        {
            case -1:
                perror("Fork Failed\n");
                exit(1);
            case 0:
                execvp (arg_tok[0], arg_tok);
                perror ("execvp has failed");
                exit(1);
            default:
                while( wait(&exitstatus) != pid );
                printf ("Child process exited with status %d, %d\n",
                        exitstatus>>8, exitstatus&0377);
        }
    }
}
```

(**note:** the addition of the header `sys/wait.h` for `wait()`)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/execvp_ls
theshell> ls -al fh
total 152
drwxr-xr-x  2 david david   4096 Jul  1  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x 32 david david 131072 Mar  3 15:16 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 david david    602 Jul  1  2018 Readme_ld_reqd_opts.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 david david    124 Jul  1  2018 conversion.c
-rw-r--r--  1 david david     30 Jul  1  2018 conversion.h
-rw-r--r--  1 david david    250 Jul  1  2018 convert_driver.c
Child process exited with status 0, 0
theshell> ^C
```

Note also, your use of macros, while clever, will usually lead to more problems than they solve. Simply writing the prompt to be displayed is a far more readable way to go. While the macro use here is trivial here, this only grows with code length and complexity.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.